# Make a model global for backbone.marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have user model which needs to be accessed in multiple views all over the site. Can I create a global model in a marionette application?

So i can access it through:

```
window.MarionetteApp.userModel
```

This is the only idea I've had so far that makes sense. Unless someone has a better way to structure a user in backbone.marionette, im open to ideas.

Comment: Is it an instance of the model, or the model definition that you need to access in multiple places ?

Comment: Well I do the same thing, I will just have one global variable called "app", any thing needs to be stored on global, I just add to app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this

```
MyApp.addInitializer(function(){
    this.currentUser = new UserModel();
});
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this approach. Your user will be available anywhere through `MyApp.currentUser` and is correctly namespaced. You have to think how you access it from other places though, as it may introduce side-effects and behaviors difficult to predict.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using [Marionette.RequestReponse](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.requestresponse.md). With it, you can do something like this:

```
MarionetteApp.reqres.setHandler('currentUser', function() {
   if(MarionetteApp.currentUser) return MarionetteApp.currentUser;

   var user = MarionetteApp.currentUser = new MarionetteApp.models.User(/* whatever */);
   return user;
});
```

And then get your model like so:

```
var user = MarionetteApp.request('currentUser');
```

Answer (score 2):

[the good example wrote David Sulc](https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/entities/header.js):

```
ContactManager.module("Entities", function(Entities, ContactManager, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){
  Entities.Header = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
      var selectable = new Backbone.Picky.Selectable(this);
      _.extend(this, selectable);
    }
  });

  Entities.HeaderCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Entities.Header,

    initialize: function(){
      var singleSelect = new Backbone.Picky.SingleSelect(this);
      _.extend(this, singleSelect);
    }
  });

  var initializeHeaders = function(){
    Entities.headers = new Entities.HeaderCollection([
      { name: "Contacts", url: "contacts", navigationTrigger: "contacts:list" },
      { name: "About", url: "about", navigationTrigger: "about:show" }
    ]);
  };

  var API = {
    getHeaders: function(){
      if(Entities.headers === undefined){
        initializeHeaders();
      }
      return Entities.headers;
    }
  };

  ContactManager.reqres.setHandler("header:entities", function(){
    return API.getHeaders();
  });
});
```